# Como modificar o filename do multer com variáveis do front?

Tags: node.js, react, multer

Bom dia, estou criando uma aplicação React e Node, e no momento preciso fazer o upload de um arquivo PDF, o código funciona bem, mas eu queria saber como que na hora de montar o filename do arquivo pelo multer, eu uso variáveis do próprio front? obrigado.

O código está da seguinte maneira:

Front:

```
const sendFile = () => {
      const dado = new FormData() 
      dado.append('file', file)
      axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/comprebem/file", dado, { // receive two parameter endpoint url ,form data 
    })
    .then(res => { // then print response status
      console.log(res.statusText)
    })
    }
```

Back:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination:"../login/public/comprebem/ibama/",
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, `unidade${Date.now()}_data${file.originalname}` )
}
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file')

app.post('/api/comprebem/file',function(req, res) {
     
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
         if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
             return res.status(500).json(err)
         } else if (err) {
             return res.status(500).json(err)
         }
    return res.status(200).send(req.file)

  })

});
```

Se alguém puder me responder também por que está dando esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele dá quando eu envio o arquivo, porém está funcionando tudo corretamente, por que existe o erro?

Comment: _`como que na hora de montar o filename do arquivo pelo multer, eu uso variáveis do próprio front?`_, poderia tentar extrai essas variaveis pelo `req` em `filename: function (req, file, cb) {...}`? Tentou fazer isso?

Comment: Eu tento usar req.var, req[var], req['var'], mas nada dá certo, me devolve undefined

Comment: `req.body.var`?

Comment: continua dando indefinido, no front eu estou dando append no State que contém a variável q eu quero levar pro back, será que estou fazendo errado? ```dado.append('file', file)
      dado.append('uni', uni) ```